# Error in withRouter params parsing Invariant Violation: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

so i've been trying to pass an argument using withRouter but i find error with Invariant Violation: You should not use Route or withRouter() outside a Router

does any of you know how to fix it? or to pass an argument use anything beside withRouter?

here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import dummy_database from '../../file_source/dummy_database.json';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import './css/description.css';

class Description extends Component {
    render() {
        var id = parseInt(this.props.match.params.id, 10);
        var contentKeys = Object.keys(dummy_database.products);
        var products = contentKeys.map((t) => 
            <p key={t}>{dummy_database.products[t]}</p>
        );

        var description='';

        for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
            if(dummy_database.products[i].id === id){
                description = dummy_database.products[i].description;
            }
        }
        return (
            <div className="description">
                <div className="descriptionTitle">
                    <h3>Description</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="descriptionText">
                    {description}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(Description);
```

and this is the button code that i use

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Details from '../../pages/details/details';


class ViewButton extends Component {
    refreshPage() {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    render() {

        var link = 'details/' + this.props.id;
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <button>
                        <Link to={link} onClick={this.refreshPage}>View Detail</Link>
                    </button>
                    <Route path={link} component={Details} />
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ViewButton;
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure this component is a child (at any level) of React Router declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [documentation for BrowserRouter:](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter)

> children: node A single child element to render.

Fix it by having one node as children of BrowserRouter

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Details from '../../pages/details/details';


class ViewButton extends Component {
    refreshPage() {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    render() {

        var link = 'details/' + this.props.id;
        return (
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                  <div>
                    <button>
                        <Link to={link} onClick={this.refreshPage}>View Detail</Link>
                    </button>
                    <Route path={link} component={Details} />
                  </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ViewButton;
```